# Why is the MDBottomAppBar not accepting MDTopAppBar as it's child?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I was learning kivyMD and while creating a Bottom Bar with a TopAppBar as its child , the BottomBar doesn't seem to accept the TopAppBar as its child.  Like in this kv file:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MyApp"
        left_action_items: [["menu"]]
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical"]]

    MDLabel:
        id: my_label
        text: "Welcome User!"
        halign: "center"

    MDBottomAppBar:

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Title"
            icon: "git"
            type: "bottom"
```

The contents of MDTopAppBar do not seem to come over on MDBottomAppBar and instead its just and empty blue space. Is there any solution for this?